# Where can I get HLK and HCK test sets for my driver to do a submission?

Tags: testing, driver, kernel-mode

I have an application kernel mode driver (software driver, no device) and I want to do hlk and hck testing for it to do a submission of merged packages (signed by EV certificate) to Microsoft.

The problem is that when I install my driver to the test system and select it in HLK Studio, I do not have any playlist to run compatibility test. Where can I get it?

I know that I can download HLK playlist from Microsoft website, but it is not in xml format whereas HLK Stdio supports only xml playlists. I tried to call this file as HLK.xml and add, but Studio writes it cannot find tests with this ids.

And I can't find any playlist for HCK Testing.

Help me, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any updates? I have same problem. Could you please provide playlist link in non-xml format that you found?

Comment: seems it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/windows-hardware-lab-kit#download-windows-hardware-compatibility-playlist.